# canvas.toDataURL not working from button listener

Tags: canvas

canvas.toDataURL returns the expected result when executed outside the button listener function but not from within the function. I have inserted alerts at various points within the function to try to troubleshoot but I am now stumped. The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<img id = "myImg" src = "testImg.JPG" alt="Cannot find image" 
onload = "showPics()" width="100" height="100">
<canvas id = "myCanvas" width="150" height="175" style = "border:5px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<button id="saveBtn">Save</button>

<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
//alert(canvas.toDataURL()); //works: returns data
const downld = document.getElementById("saveBtn");

downld.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
downld.style.background="red"; //button turns red when clicked
const link=document.createElement("a");
link.download="image.png";
alert(link.download); //works to here: returns image.png
alert(canvas.width); // works
alert(canvas.toDataURL()); //doesn't work
link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
alert(mylink.href); //returns nothing
link.click();
link.remove();
});

function showPics(){
//const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const img = document.getElementById("myImg");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alerts were added at various points for troubleshooting.